# Recaptcha v3 initialization interrupted

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Recaptcha v3 initialization is not completing when using the production site.
The logo is no longer appearing and if I try to submit the form I'm getting this error : "Uncaught Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js"

It's working when I'm using it on localhost from my PC

The only difference between the dev and the prod are the keys.

Any idea to why it's not loading properly ?

Changed the keys.
Tried on other web browsers.

Comment: Can you post your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 main ways I believe this is caused:

1. Your domain name should just be the domain. `apple.com`, not `https://apple.com`
2. Make sure you are including the sitekey in the render param when you add the script tag:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<v3_site_key>"></script>`

I've gotten the error when I forgot to provide the site key here (originally thought I only had to pass it in as the first argument to `grecaptcha.execute`)